# How to execute a bash command when you login

Tags: 12.10

Since my Ubuntu system has some problem keeping of track of time, I want to add a bash script somewhere that has the `ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` command in it to reset the time to the correct time when i log in. Where would I put this so the system does this when I login, not boot? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's common to put commands like this in the `~/.profile` script, which is executed at login.

I'd personally recommend using `ntpd` instead of `ntpdate` as it is a service which runs in the background and constantly checks and corrects the time.

To install it, run `sudo apt-get remove ntpdate` to remove `ntpdate`, then `sudo apt-get install ntpd`.

Comment: Both Noted. If you don't mind, how would I go about configuring ntpd once installed?

Comment: The default configuration should work out of the box. If it doesn't, you can see the official help pages here https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/NTP.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding it to the `Startup Applications` in your user?

Comment: I have not, how do you set those?

Comment: search for `Startup Applications` in your dash, i dunno if it has been renamed or w/e. It used to be pretty easy to add a new one. If `ntpdate` needs `sudo` however, it might not work..

Comment: Would you care to make your answer a bit more elaborate? Comments get removed eventually.